# How to access local files from docker image running springboot using the file URI?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot application running in a docker image. We can access local API's using `host.docker.internal`, so is there any way to access local files using its URL, i.e. for eg:
`file:///Users/ayush.singhal/Downloads/arguments.csv`

I know about accessing the file by mounting the volume, but I am trying to do it from internal program itself that is running in the docker image.

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that the container filesystem is isolated from the host filesystem, so you can't do this without explicitly adding a bind mount.  Consider running your process outside of Docker if accessing host files is a primary goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mount point using "volumes" in the docker-compose file that will point to a folder in the host system. By default, docker isolates the container from everything else.